# Find all natural solutions to $x^2+2y^2 = z^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares

> I need to find all natural solutions to $x^2 + 2y^2 = z^2$

What I tried: I did $\pmod 2$ to the equation receiving $z^2 - x^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$.

Then there are two possibilities:

1. $x^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$,  $z^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ then $x \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ ,  $z \equiv 0 \pmod 2$
2. $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ ,  $z^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ then $x \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ ,  $z \equiv 1 \pmod 2$

In the first possibility I divide the equation by $2$ infinitely many times
and get a contradiction. So I get only the trivial $(0,0,0)$ solution.

In the second one I'm stuck... Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every number that is not of the form $4k+2$ can be written as a difference of two squares, hence a solution exists for every even $y$. Just an example, $y=6$. Then $2y^2 = 2^3\cdot 3^2$, so by setting $(z-x)=2\cdot 3$ and $(z+x)=2^2\cdot 3$ we get the solution $(x,y,z)=(3,6,9)$.